# Perfect modules for the Beilinson algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, koszul-duality, koszul-algebras

The Beilinson algebra $A=A_n$ is a finite dimensional quiver algebra that is derived equivalent to the category of coherent sheaves of $\mathcal{P}^n$. See for example https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11425-012-4388-9 on top of page 1155 for quiver and relations. For $n=2$ one obtains the Kronecker quiver algebra and $A_n$ is for all $n$ a Koszul algebra.

I noted that all simple $A$ modules $S$ are perfect, that is they satisfy $grade S= pdim S$.
Now for a general perfect module M with grade $g$, one can look at the module $U_M:=Ext_A^g(M,A)$ and $U_M$ is again perfect with the same grade and $U_{U_M}=M$.
Now one can look at the module $W_A:= \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{n}{U_{S_i}}$ when $S_i$ are the simple $A_n$-modules.

I noted that for $n=2,3,4$, the module $W_A$ is a tilting module (we just have to show that $Ext_A^i(W_A,W_A)=0$ for all $i>0$, since $W_A$ has finite projective dimension as $A_n$ has finite global dimension and $W_A$ has the right number of indecomposable direct summands) and that the tilted algebra $B:=End_A(W_A)$ is isomorphic to the Koszul dual of $A$. Koszul duality seems very related to the relations $U_{U_S}=S$ (since Koszul duality is also an operation "of order 2") for all simple $A$-modules so one might expect an easy proof without much calculations for general $n$.

> Question: Is this true in general and is there even a bigger meaning (or even geometric interpretation)?